# Add link/popup on embed video

Tags: javascript, video, onclick, embed, clickable

I created below code for showing youtube video.
But i want to make it now clickable video.
When visitor click on video, then open an url in new tab or popup window.

```html
<iframe class="youtube_iframe" width="710" height="493" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/<?=$cal;?>?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" style="padding-top: 10px;" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Please help me?

Comment: You want the video to link to another URL after clicking on it again once it's playing?

Comment: use `window.open("http://www.yourwebsite.com");` to open the URL in a new window.